# RoR index with where and join : how to filter with associated model criterion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, where-clause, one-to-many

I am trying to to filter some stuff in a RoR index using where and joins.

I have

- a Project model
- and a Milestone model which belongs_to Project, and a "date" column

=>

```
class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

and

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :milestones
end
```

And I am trying to create a list of projects with all those which have their last milestone in a specific year.

I am trying this but it does not seem to work.

```
@projects_2021 = Project.joins(:milestones).where("milestones.last.date.year = 2021")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Projects.joins(:milestones).where(milestones: { column_name: "aaa" })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How could I select the last one with your solution ?

Comment: You mean the last one from returned data? .last should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot sectasy ! It is working with a particular value. How can I do with a range of dates ?
         Projects.joins(:milestones).where(milestones: { column_name > 2021 })

Comment: ```Project.joins(:milestones).where(milestones: { column_name: Date.current..(Date.current + 45.days) }```

Should work